# Removing/Replacing reserved or invalid url characters in a string

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm in the process of creating sef urls for my app. I just encountered an error where one of my objects contains the following characters:

```
@#!*
```

My desired output is the following where anything illegal outside of reserved/unreserved will get replaced by an underscore:

```
@_!*
```

I planned on using this regular expression to filter the bad characters:

```
[^]A-Za-z0-9_.~!*''();:@&=+$,/?#[%-]+
```

And do the replacement via `gsub`

```
'@#!*'.gsub!(/[^]_.~!*''();:@&=+$,/?#[%-]+/, '_')
```

But not getting anything returned at all. What's going on here?

Comment: Your regex does not match the `@#!*` string, see https://rubular.com/r/nqWfd5i6DbCkcj Also, you need to escape `/` that is part of the regex literal. And you must escape square  brackets inside the character class.

Comment: I basically just want to replace invalid url characters. I found that regex on another post. Not sure if it's fitting to my situation.

Answer (score 0):

```
'<@#_!*>'.gsub(/[\[\]^A-Za-z0-9.~!*''();:@&=+$,\/?#%+-]/, '_')
  #=> "<_____>"
```

'[', ']' and '/' must be escaped, '-' must be at the beginning or end of the character class and '^' cannot be at the beginning of the character class (the character class being denoted by the outer '[' and ']' characters). There's no point in replacing '*' with '*' so I've not included that character in the character class.

Do you wish to also replace '<' and '>'? Are you sure letters and digits "reserved characters"?

Comment: My intention is to to take out anything illegal for a url. Looking back at this letters and numbers would be too much. I'll update my post to reflect this.